# gdb takes only the first parameter

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I'm trying to debug a program which takes on the command line a couple of arguments.
Inside the main I print out the arguments as follows:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
  printf("param%d=%s\n", i, argv[i]);
}
```

when I run my program without gdb, like this

```
"program img.jpg 1 2"
```

I get as output:

```
param0: program
param1: img.jpg
param2: 1
param3: 2
```

When I run it with gdb like this:

```
"program img.jpg 1 2"
```

I only get

```
param0: img.jpg
```

on one hand `img.jpg` should be param1, also param2 and 3 are missing.
Is there a special way to specify command line params to gdb that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify parameters when you run the program.

First you should invoke the debugger with

```
$ gdb <binary_file_name (executable)>
```

Than you start the program also passing command line arguments:

```
(gdb) r p1 -p2 --p3 p4=p5
```

<sub>Side note: I think this solution is more flexible than using the `--args` flag, because you can launch your program multiple times with different parameters without quitting the current `gdb` instance (e.g., you keep your breakpoints).</sub>

Comment: it works, many thanks.I'll check it as the correct answer soon

Comment: you can also use "set args" within gdb, and then just call "run".

Answer (score 1):

You are now sending parameters to `gdb` instead of `program`. In order to pass parameters to `program` you can use the `--args` parameter for `gdb`.

```
gdb --args program img.jpg 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--args` option to tell `gdb` to pass the arguments to the program being debugged:

```
> gdb --args program img.jpg 1 2
```

Alternatively, you can launch `gdb` without the arguments, and then supply them to the `run` command:

```
> gdb program
(gdb) run img.jpg 1 2
```